# Unambiguous grammar for regular expressions

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, regular-expressions

How to define a non ambiguous grammar for regular expressions on the $\Sigma =
 \{a,b\}$ alphabet?

Given that:

If $\Theta = \{+, ^*, (,),\cdot, \emptyset\}$ is a set of symbols

A *regular expression* on $\Sigma$ is a string such that one of the following condition applies

1. $r = \emptyset$
2. $r \in \Sigma $
3. $r = (s+t)$ or $ r = (s\cdot t)$ or $r = s^*$

Comment: Ok fade2black so now the grammar $G$ should recognize regular expressions. I wonder if i can use $\epsilon$ instead of $\emptyset$ in the grammar

Comment: $\epsilon$ cannot be used instead of $\emptyset$ since they have different meanings in regular expressions. The first one corresponds to a regular set with a single element $\epsilon$, the empty string, while the other is just an empty set containing no strings.

Comment: I think your question already answers itself. You're on the right track.

Comment: What are *r*, *s*, and *t* ?

Answer (score 3):

I need to define a *context free grammar* to recognize regular expression. I know also that CF grammars are used to recognize mathematical expressions. so the grammar $G$ should recognize regular expressions.

$G:$

$ E \rightarrow E + T \mid T $

$ T \rightarrow  T \cdot F \mid F $

$ F \rightarrow(E) \mid E^* \mid a\mid b\mid\emptyset$

Comment: $F^*$, not $E^*$

Comment: @rici $F^*$ or $E^*$, the grammar will generate the same set, won't it?

Comment: @fade yes, but only one of them is unambiguous.

Comment: @rici did you find a string having two different leftmost derivations? Could you share it?

Comment: @fade: I didn't look very hard :-). Try $a+b^*$

Comment: @rici, of course, :-). $E\rightarrow E + T$ or $E\rightarrow T$. Thanks.